# android alarm not getting received by the application

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am facing consistency issue while setting alarms inside my application wherein the alarm gets delivered sometimes but other times the pending intent does not gets delivered to my application.

The way I am trying to test is by changing my local device time and check if I am getting the alarm or not.

I can see the alarm getting triggered from the alarm manager because this log comes up

```
V AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 0 when =1508253750804 package=com.x.xoperation =*walarm*:com.x.x/x.AlarmReceiver
```

Does android control the delivery of an alarm based upon whether the application is in the background or not? Any insights around this area would really help.

Code For AlarmManager

```
public static void SetNotification(int id, long delayMs, String title, String message, String ticker, int sound, int vibrate,
                                   int lights, String largeIconResource, String smallIconResource, int bgColor, String bundle, String dataString)
{
    Context currentActivity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    String arr[] = new String[]{id+"", delayMs+"", title, message, ticker, sound+""};
    String fStr = "";
    for (String temp:arr
         ) {
        fStr += temp+":";
    }
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Input message = "+fStr);

    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("color", bgColor);
    intent.putExtra("sound", sound == 1);
    intent.putExtra("vibrate", vibrate == 1);
    intent.putExtra("lights", lights == 1);
    intent.putExtra("l_icon", largeIconResource);
    intent.putExtra("s_icon", smallIconResource);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    intent.putExtra("dataString", dataString);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(currentActivity,
            id, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    am.cancel(pendingIntent);

    long finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + delayMs;

    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,finalTime, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "event fired finalTime = "+ finalTime);
}
```

Is this because of the doze and app standby which android has introduced ? or is because of some issue on our side.

Comment: Can you please post your code here for alarm manager?

Comment: are you updating pending intent every time? when you create new alarm?

Comment: @SamirBhatt have added the code for alarm manager

Comment: @Karthik i do add new alarms but then the id for all of those are different. I dont think that is a problem because the alarm manager is firing the alarm.